# How to download a zip/rar(content) in ASCII by a ftp

Tags: ftp, filezilla, binary-files

I am trying to download a file from a **ftp** server, the file is **Zip/rar** and I am using **filezilla**.

I download the file in Acssi but **the problem** comes when I unzip the file  and the files are in binary. there is a way to convert the files in  ASCII?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct term is [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).
You must not download or upload binary files (such as zip or rar) using ASCII/text mode. Such files must be transferred using binary mode.
Binary mode ensure files are 100% byte-identical between source and destination. Text mode actually reads in each character from the file and potentially converts it.
There's no trivial way to convert a corrupted file from text mode into binary.
Your safest course of action to re-download that file using the correct mode.